# What does this code mean in the source engine

Tags: source-code, source-engine, quake3

I am working on a project in which I analyze acceleration in the Source engine. Being that I have very basic knowledge of computer science, I am not very proficient in understanding the syntax.

The code that I am having trouble with is:

mv->m_vecVelocity[i] += accelspeed * wishdir[i];

I am confused as to what the " mv-> " is. Thank you for your help in advance.

I am getting the code from here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/56accfdb9c4abd32ae1dc26b2e4cc87898cf4dc1/sp/src/game/shared/gamemovement.cpp

line 1745

In particular I am interested in knowing what mv is and what the -> is

Comment: To read C, learn C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's object instance of class [CMoveData](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/56accfdb9c4abd32ae1dc26b2e4cc87898cf4dc1/sp/src/game/shared/igamemovement.h). It handles movement.

This can be found from code file you posted:

```
CMoveData *pMove 
mv = pMove;
```

So, `mv` is `CMoveData`

The `->` is the arrow operator. You can access class pointers using (for example) `mv->m_nPlayerHandle.Get()`. This is somewhat hard area to understand. There are couple of good answers on stackoverflow about this

[Difference of pointer and reference variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

[Array operator vs dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716293/arrow-operator-and-dot-operator-class-pointer)

Comment: Thank you. I also learned that -> is a pointer. (as you can see I am a total noob)

so I am assuming that mv->m_vecvelocity[i] gets the value of velocity of the movement?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ^^, I couldn't give you an up arrow since I am new, but take this check mark instead.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, "mv->" means "the following property of mv".

So, "mv->m_vecVelocity" means "the vector velocity property of the movedata".

"mv" represents kinematic state of a physical object.